# Use of UserRecordAccess in queries during System.runAs()

Tags: apex, test-setup, apex-managed-sharing, userrecordaccess

I am building a feature that uses apex-managed sharing to define granular levels of record sharing. I would like to have end-to-end tests that sets up records, users, runs the feature, then validates that some test users have access to records that I expect, and that other test users don't have access to records they shouldn't.

I thought that using System.runAs(), plus queries against the objects using the UserRecordAccess joined relationship, I could assert that the HasReadAccess/HasEditAccess values are what I'm expecting.

However, the behavior I'm seeing doesn't seem to give me the values I'm expecting, and I'm wondering if what I'm seeing is a bug or if it is expected behavior that perhaps I don't understand.

This code is very simplified for the purposes of highlighting the behavior I'm wondering about.

```java
@isTest
private with sharing class SharingRunAsTest {
    static CustomObject__c createRecord() {
        CustomObject__c record = new CustomObject__c(Name='test');
        insert record;
        return record;
    }

    static User createUser(String alias) {
        /*  using a profile that has read and edit 
            on an object that has OWD set to private */
        User newUser = new User(
            Alias = alias,
            Email = alias + '@test.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = alias,
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'TestProfile'].Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = alias + '@test.com'
        );
        insert newUser;
        return newUser;
    }   

    static void createShare(String userId, String recordId) {
        insert new CustomObject__share(
            ParentId = recordId,
            UserOrGroupId = userId,
            RowCause = 'MySharingReason__c', // a sharing reason that exists on CustomObject__c
            AccessLevel = 'Read'
        );
    }

    @isTest
    static void runTest() {
        CustomObject__c record = createRecord();
        User userA = createUser('user_a'); // user that won't have access
        User userB = createUser('user_b'); // user that will have access

        createShare(userB.Id, record.Id);
    
        // Now I have a test record created, shared to user b, but not shared to user A
        // I would like to assert that user A does not have access to this record
        // In this simplified scenario, you could argue that I should just test whether or
        // not user A has access to any records, but our actual feature has more complicated
        // scenarios, such as testing that a user has access to some but not all records, 
        // and/or they have read but not edit access, etc

        System.runAs(userA) {

            CustomObject__c[] recordsJoinedWithAccess = [
                SELECT 
                    Name, 
                    UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, 
                    UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
                FROM CustomObject__c
            ];

            System.debug('==== recordsJoinedWithAccess ====');
            System.debug(recordsJoinedWithAccess.size()); // 0... great! what I'd expect

            UserRecordAccess[] userRecordAccessQuery = [
                SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess
                FROM UserRecordAccess
                WHERE RecordId = :record.Id
                AND UserId = :userA.Id
            ];

            System.debug('==== userRecordAccessQuery ====');
            System.debug('size: ' + userRecordAccessQuery.size());  // 1 
            System.debug('hasReadAccess: ' + userRecordAccessQuery[0].HasReadAccess); // false
            System.debug('hasEditAccess: ' + userRecordAccessQuery[0].HasEditAccess); // false


            WithoutSharingQuery query = new WithoutSharingQuery();
            
            UserRecordAccess[] userRecordAccessQueryWithoutSharing = query.getRecordAccess(userA.Id);

            System.debug('==== userRecordAccessQueryWithoutSharing ====');
            System.debug('size: ' + userRecordAccessQueryWithoutSharing.size()); // 1
            System.debug('hasReadAccess: ' + userRecordAccessQueryWithoutSharing[0].HasReadAccess); // false
            System.debug('hasEditAccess: ' + userRecordAccessQueryWithoutSharing[0].HasEditAccess); // false
            
            CustomObject__c[] recordsJoinedWithAccessWithoutSharing = query.getRecords();

            System.debug('==== recordsJoinedWithAccessWithoutSharing ====');
            System.debug('size: ' + recordsJoinedWithAccessWithoutSharing.size()); // 1
            /* !!! WEIRD STUFF HERE !!! */
            System.debug('hasReadAccess: ' + recordsJoinedWithAccessWithoutSharing[0].UserRecordAcces.HasReadAccess); // this returns true???
            System.debug('hasEditAccess: ' + recordsJoinedWithAccessWithoutSharing[0].UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess); // this returns true???
        }
    }

    without sharing class WithoutSharingQuery {

        WithoutSharingQuery() {}

        CustomObject__c[] getRecords() { 
            return [
                SELECT Name, UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
                FROM CustomObject__c
            ];
        }


        UserRecordAccess[] getRecordAccess(String userId) {
            Map<Id, CustomObject__c> records = new Map<Id, CustomObject__c>(getRecords());
            return [
                SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess
                FROM UserRecordAccess
                WHERE RecordId IN :records.keySet()
                AND UserId = :userId
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

**Is this expected behavior, that UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess and UserRecord.HasEditAccess returns true on records I expect to be false for the runAs user, or a bug with runAs + System Mode that I should be reporting?**

For what its worth, when I make direct queries on UserRecordAccess without using runAs() (eg `SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = testUser.Id`), the values I get are what I would expect (false), not what I'm seeing with runAs(testUser).

I've posted a github repo with this simplified code and custom object that can be repro'ed in a scratch org: https://github.com/jkranz-rk/testingRunAs

Comment: What happens if you try this with the new `WITH SYSTEM_MODE` query? Does this change the results of your test? Alternatively, what happens if you run that record through `Security.stripInaccessible`? Does it then fix the data? I'm kind of leaning towards "this is probably a bug", because HasReadAccess and HasEditAccess both have default values of "false", so if nothing was returned, I'd expect it to be at minimum default false. I'll do some more research on this, though.

Comment: Yep, the query in my sample repro here in SystemModeQuery is actually already using WITH SYSTEM_MODE. Thinking this is a bug, but it's layers deep so I appreciate the set of eyes on it. I'm not sure what I'd expect stripInaccessible to do to the fields on the joined UserRecordAccess relationship

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're suggesting. Adding WITH SYSTEM_MODE to the first query has no effect, because WITH SYSTEM_MODE falls back to inherit it's context sharing mode, and since this is inside runAs() it runs it with sharing applied, returning no records

Comment: Yeah, just trying to identify if it's sharing or the UserAccessObject that's wrong. It's just a hypotheses, but hopefully it yields results.

Comment: Okay, looks like SYSTEM_MODE itself doesn't have an effect. Adding it to the first query or removing it from the second didn't have an effect. It seems related specifically to querying for records that join the UserRecordAccess table while using without sharing while in runAs(). updated the sample repro code with this.

Comment: IIRC you cannot use custom sharing reasons in apex...?

Comment: @PhilW you can definitely use custom sharing reasons in apex, but in this case its a bit of a red herring: it doesn't directly factor in the behavior at issue, I'm just including it as a way to show why I need to test for user access at this granularity.